# finding which array my string is in and sending it into a variable javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the print the location of an array for instance below I have 7 arrays inside 1 array.

```
 var jobTypes = [
        ["engineering", "engineer"], //Engineer Filter
        ["marketing", "growth hacker", "selling warrior"], // Marketing Filter
        ["sales"], // Sales Filter
        ["customer success"], //Customer Filter
        ["design"], // Design Filter
        ["product"], // Product Filter
        ["finance", "hr"], // Finance Filter
        ["other"] // Other Filter
    ];
```

I want to find which array my string is in and send that value(the array number) to a variable. I want to assign a value depending on which of string of an array is called for instance:

```
var foo = jobTypes[1][2]; //selling warrior
```

which would give foo the value of 2 since it's in the 2nd array regardless of which order the string is at in the nested array.

```
foo == 1
```

another example:

```
var bar = jobTypes[2][0];
```

which should give me the bar value of 2:

```
bar == 2
```

Comment: Whhhhaaat?!?!! This makes no sense at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    function whichArray(arrays, search) {
       for(var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
           for(var j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++){
               if(arrays[i][j] === search) return i;
           }
       }
       return -1;
    }

    var result = whichArray(jobTypes, "selling warrior");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over the outer array and call `.indexOf()` on each inner array and return the array index if you find a match:

```
function findDepartment(data, dept) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].indexOf(dept) !== -1) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And, a working snippet:

```js
    var jobTypes = [
            ["engineering", "engineer"], //Engineer Filter
            ["marketing", "growth hacker", "selling warrior"], // Marketing Filter
            ["sales"], // Sales Filter
            ["customer success"], //Customer Filter
            ["design"], // Design Filter
            ["product"], // Product Filter
            ["finance", "hr"], // Finance Filter
            ["other"] // Other Filter
        ];

    function findDepartment(data, dept) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].indexOf(dept) !== -1) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    var index = findDepartment(jobTypes, "selling warrior");
    document.write(index);
```

Comment: Remember to add a polyfill for indexOf if you need IE8 support.

Comment: @clean_coding - Is anyone still coding for IE8?  Polyfill is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) if needed.

Comment: Yes, I do for our large B2B clients, unfortunately. :)

Comment: @clean_coding - Wow, remind me never to work for a company that requires their employees to still use IE8 as their browser for B2B.  That must be absolute torture and a security nightmare.

Comment: Well I'm not a frontend developer, so It's not that bad - but yeah just the other day I got a screenshot from a customer who was using IE7...

Comment: @clean_coding - Just because they "can" doesn't mean they "should".  My web development would be slowed to a crawl if I had to fully test everything in IE7 and IE8.  I would think that the security implications alone of running such an old browser would drive companies to upgrade.  IE7 is 9 years old.  That's 20 lifetimes in terms of internet security.  I know you don't get to make the rules where you work, but I'm surprised that some of your client companies are still so behind-the-times that they have users running IE7.

Comment: This works as well as the first answer. Is the advantage of this less code and being faster?

Comment: @DanielPlasRivera - Yes, you're right.  `.indexOf()` is substantially faster than a manual iteration (and less code).  That's often the advantage of the built-in methods.